# Modern SharePoint online List/library theme not being updated when "Change the look"

Tags: theme, composed-looks, modern-document-library, modern-experience

Since the new modern look in SharePoint online, a couple of our users are complaining that their libraries do not match the theme on their sites. For example the homepage of the site seem to follow the Microsoft Blue Office theme, but when you go into a list or library, the text and the horizontal bar is pink.

I've tried to choose a different theme in Change the look, but the modern lists and libraries are still pink.

These sites have been migrated from a 2010 site originally, but the list is a brand new list created inside SharePoint online, could the migration be the reason the theme isn't being pushed down?

Comment: Did the proposed answer solve your problem? I just ran into this too, on a brand new site

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue on a site which wasn't migrated. So it has nothing to do with your migration.
Try changing it to a different color, like red. That solved the problem for me.

Comment: Hi Andreas, do you mean change to a red theme in "Change the look"? Then switch back to the blue afterwards?

Comment: Yes, that's what i mean